# In IntelliJ Ultimate, how can I set the code style to set absolute import before relative import?

Tags: intellij-idea, coding-style, intellij-15

In IntelliJ Ultimate, we are working on a react application and this is our code styles:

```
<code_scheme name="Default" version="173">
  <HTMLCodeStyleSettings>
    <option name="HTML_SPACE_INSIDE_EMPTY_TAG" value="true" />
  </HTMLCodeStyleSettings>
  <JSCodeStyleSettings version="0">
    <option name="USE_DOUBLE_QUOTES" value="false" />
    <option name="FORCE_QUOTE_STYlE" value="true" />
    <option name="ENFORCE_TRAILING_COMMA" value="WhenMultiline" />
    <option name="SPACES_WITHIN_IMPORTS" value="true" />
  </JSCodeStyleSettings>
  <XML>
    <option name="XML_SPACE_INSIDE_EMPTY_TAG" value="true" />
  </XML>
  <codeStyleSettings language="JavaScript">
    <option name="IF_BRACE_FORCE" value="3" />
    <indentOptions>
      <option name="INDENT_SIZE" value="2" />
      <option name="TAB_SIZE" value="2" />
    </indentOptions>
  </codeStyleSettings>
</code_scheme>
```

Is there a way to set the code style to set absolute import before relative import?

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import User from './User';
```

bad

```
import User from './User';
import _ from 'lodash';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable sorting the imports by the module name – that way all the application imports that start with `./` will go after the imports from node_modules. This option is available in **Preferences | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript or TypeScript | Imports**, **Sort imports by modules**.

For advanced imports sorting/grouping support, please vote for [WEB-21182](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21182)

Comment: Hi, are you sure about this? I have just tried to set this and format the code with `CTRL+SHIFT+F`, this was not sorted by imports by module: `import LocalToggle from '../../components/LocalToggle';
import ThemeToggle from '@bootstrap-styled/redux/lib/ThemeToggle';`

Comment: please check if you have *Optimize imports* enabled in *Reformat file* dialog